# Play! Framework Markdown

Tags: playframework, markdown

First: I never used Markdown and I am new to the play! framework.

I want to use markdown in a project and I found a play! [markdown module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/markdown).

But I don't even get the sample application which I got from the related git site to work.

So has anyone used markdown with play! yet?

Or does someone has a good alternative to this module or even a good alternative to markdown?

Comment: What do you mean by not being able to get it to work? Have you installed the module with 'play install markdown', created a new app and changed the dependencies.conf?

Comment: what exactly do you need? Serverside conversion, or client side conversion or both of the Markdown files?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented markdown in play using this code:
https://github.com/sirthias/pegdown

I found it to be the best solution. It is implemented in java but there is no scala solution as far as I know. It seems you are new to play! and if you use scala you need to research how to use java code from scala there is plenty examples around.

Alternative to markdown would be BBCode.